# Named Range Not Accessible

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA I try to reference a named range that is in another sheet.  For some reason, it is not found.  The name comes up blank.

[image]

The code is very simple.

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
        strDVList = Range("Lists!PillarList").RefersTo
        MsgBox ("String: " + strDVList)
        frmDVList.Show
    End If
```

It is activated if you click in column A for the rows in the table.

Comment: You stated *I try to reference a named range that is in another sheet* but you have not specific reference to any `worksheet` object in your code. for example; `strDVList = Sheet1.Range("Lists!PillarList").RefersTo` is specifically referring to `Sheet1`. We also don't know what `Target` or `rngDV` are without the rest of your code.

Comment: The code was on google drive.  Someone seems to have edited my description to remove it.  https://drive.google.com/open?id=17RNfuC1gBet6glX-1MfCQ9oWmx0AhLbq

Comment: Where did you find sheet1?  My code doesn't refert to sheet1.  It is refering to "Lists!"

Comment: I didn't *find* sheet1, I used it as an example. To make it a bit clearer, consider `strDVList = Sheets("Lists").Range("PillarList").RefersTo`. I also didn't open your workbook or view the code in it. Consider posting more relevant code if in your question (which is preferred) if there is anything that should be added for context or clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The MsgBox you want needs this syntax because you aren't asking about the name of the range but the range of the Name.

```
MsgBox "String = " & Names("PillarList").RefersTo
```

Comment: The real problem is that I am trying to change this definition of a string                                  
         strList = Target.Validation.Formula1
         strList = Right(strList, Len(strList) - 1)
         strDVList = strList
To refer instead to the content of a named range.  This string is used in the initialization of a listbox.

Comment: The real problem is that you aren't telling us your real problem which is "in the initialization of a listbox". Consider upending this entire thread by shifting the goal posts by giving your question its real focus or asking a new question. Meanwhile, if you have a range named `MyRange` and this range refers to A3:C31 then `Range("A3:A31")` and `Range("MyRange")` will have the exact same effect whether you wish to assign its value to a listbox or a range of cells. There should never be a need to convert one syntax to another, one name to another, the name to the reference that it stands for.